# Keycloak 18 proper configuration

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak to authenticate a user for a Vaadin application. The Vaadin application creates its own user session after successful authentication with Keycloak. I need the user to be able to change the password and email address.

Now I do not quite understand how to implement it correctly. There is a user Keycloak console that has this kind of functionality. But, for example, when a user changes their email address, the user is not prompted to confirm that new email address until a new login. Should I disable the Keycloak user console and e.g. use the Keycloak REST API directly from the Vaadin app to perform email/password changes? Or should I keep using Keycloak's custom console and configure it there?

What is the proper way to deal with such things with Keycloak? In case of Keycloak API I'd really appreciate the examples of API calls which should I perform in order to change the user password and email.